# Procedure Oracle return NUMBER -1 , but php return 4294967295

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

My code:

```
`   <?php
...
$stid = oci_parse($conn, " BEGIN my_procedure(:Key, :RetCod );  END; ");
        oci_bind_by_name($stid,':Key',$key,-1,SQLT_CHR);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid,':RetCod',$retCod,-1,SQLT_INT);
        oci_execute($stid);
        return $retCod;
?>`
```

the procedure Oracle return -1 but php return 4294967295
thanks for your help

Comment: Please don't reply to yourself, just edit your question! It's embarrassing to see grownups talking to themselves... :)

Comment: `4294967295` is the max value for an unsigned 32bit integer. Which with an unsigned 32bit integer, `-1` will overflow back to the highest value.

Comment: @Mihai Just curious, but how would that help? I don't even see a `SQLT_UIN` constant on the php manual page and I'm assuming that would force it to unsigned if it did exist which is exactly what is happening here, -1 is the value OP is getting back for an unsigned value.

Comment: SQLT_UIN return null, in doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php , SQLT_UIN dont exist

Comment: SQLT_UIN is not suported

Comment: How did you inspect the content of `$retCod` ? Maybe this is when you display the value that you introduced a signed->unsigned error ?

Comment: i inspect the content with print